# struts 2 load a page in div

Tags: java, javascript, html, struts2

[image]

i have an image of my home page and i am wondering if it is posssible in struts2 to load all other pages such as products services facilities etc. in the red div in the middle of the home page. im new in struts 2 so im not sure if it is even possible please point me out on how to do this it will be appreciated

UPDATE: with some explanation i got from sir Rugal i came up with this code but its not working im running out of ideas. i put and ID to the red div as workplace

```
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li id="services"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li id="facilities"><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
                    <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<script>
$('#products').click(function(){
    $('#workplace').load('pages/products.jsp');
});
$('#services').click(function(){
    $('#workplace').load('pages/services.jsp');
});
$('#facilities').click(function(){
    $('#workplace').load('pages/facilities.jsp');
});
$('#contact').click(function(){
    $('#workplace').load('pages/contact.jsp');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think loading resource into html is not the responsibility of `struts` framework. you need to do it in HTML generator like `jsp` `jsf` or just use html+js

Comment: @Rugal no java involvement here?you know a tutorial on this what is this method called?

Comment: Did you see any Struts tag in your code? or did you see any embed java code?  As for tutorial on jsp or others, please google as there is quantities of resources on internet!

Comment: @Rugal ive done what you google but the result im looking for is not met..can you my code its a jsp code that ive made with java brain tutorial

Comment: sorry I can not catch you? can ask it again?

Comment: i wanted to know if its possible to load a page for example in my image above if i click product the product page will load in the red are?im learning struts2 in java brain they teach you the basic but they didnt tackle this are and also they didnt tackle on how to make image gallery or image side shows you have idea on these matters?

Comment: I think not, struts is a `backend` framework exists in server side that can not affect the client browser. Here you have two strategy to achieve this: first one is submit form and them jump into another page to show the image you want; another is if you need to do the fascinating clicking then a picture turned out without refresh whole page, you need to use `Ajax` in `java script`. Java and Javascript are totally different thing!  But be easy, JS and Ajax is very easy at first use~!

Comment: @Rugal i see so what i need to do is learn Ajax and Java Script to do the loading thing what struts 2 does is mainly on connecting my web page to database is that what you are trying to say here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44749/discussion-between-rugal-and-hak-hak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use struts2 tiles for your problem. Create your base layout using tiles. your layout is similar to the layout in this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-tiles-plugin-tutorial-with-example-in-eclipse/). So all you need is to have your menu in header part of layout. On click of button or menu youy call a particular action whic inturn call a particular tile definition which will have your concerned jsp page in the middle :)

Comment: yes when i saw the tutorial i know that its almost the same what im having trouble with is how do i set the button click to get the specific jsp?what i tried is a code from php but i cant convert it to jsp/strust code any idea on how to do it please show me

Comment: Use the same tutorial.. considering your html in update your li would look like  <li id="products"><a href="producePage">Products</a></li>... Where productPage will be your struts action which will call a tile definition called productTile having products.jsp in body of base layout

Comment: i had a work around on my problem what i did is just to include the header footer and side bar in my home , product,service etc. page and i think its doing good.its not that code redundant but its much better than coding everything in every page.thank you for your ideas i might be able to use it in some other project

Comment: 1 question im loading it a bit slow do you it has something to do with the code?or my pc is just slow lol

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct then It may be a solution.

Create all your contents that you want to display in a `div` tag of other page. In a different page Call that JSP in that `div` using following tag

```
  <%@ include file="yourPage.jsp"%>
```

Links of those menus create them in `yourPage.jsp` use above Tag wherever you want to include this page.

This solution is not from Struts2 if you want in struts2 refer this [Struts2 Tile Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_tiles.htm)

Create Whatever the stuff that you want in that red color div create  as a seperate JSP file and include that `JSP File`

for example

```
  Your main jsp page--- 
      main.jsp

         <body>
               <div id="someDiv">
                </div>
                <div id="yourredDiv">
                    //here you include that jSP page.
                         <%@ include file="path/yourPage.jsp"%> 
                 </div>
            </body>
        Now in yourpage.jsp

              you create the html components whatever you want.
```

Comment: i will try to make it work. what im trying to do here is i have a home page with a red div in it and if i click the product button the product page will load inside the red div that is what the image is for

Comment: Try it That worked for me. In that `red div` use above mentioned tag.

Comment: can you explain this to me further i can understand i tried making it this way i have an action in that div and when the user clicks a button an action will pop and load a page but its not working how to i use the <%@ include file="yourPage.jsp"%> tag? can you show me how its done

Comment: how does it connect to the button that loads a specific page?example when i click products button how will it load the product page?sorry im new in struts